# Entity Framework, Get element from related table based on includes

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I recognize that this question has been asked in various forms before, but none of them that I have read quite give me what I need.

Question: Given the model below, and only knowing the client ID, how can I get a List that consists of the Uid of each activity that the client is permitted to perform?

[image: EF Model]

I start with code something like the code below, but don't know where to go from there. I assume that it has something to do with a select statement - but my ignorance of LINQ is overwhelming me :)

```
public List<string> GetClientAndPermittedActivities ( int clientId )
{
    var permittedActivities = ReadAllRaw()
        .Where(c => c.Id == clientId)
        .Include("ClientType")
        .Include("Role")
        .Include("PermittedActivities")
        .Include("Activities");


}

internal IQueryable<TE> ReadAllRaw ()
{
    return base.ReadAll();
}

// READ (ALL)
internal IQueryable<T> ReadAll ()
{
    return DbSet;
}

private void SetContext ( DbContext context )
{
    this.Context = context;
    this.DbSet = Context.Set<T>();
}
```

Comment: What is `ReadAllRaw()`? Is `Uid` string?

Comment: Yes, sorry - ReadAllRaw just returns the dbset for the context, and yes, Uid is a string. I added that to my question for clarity - thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method can looks like this:

```
public List<string> GetClientAndPermittedActivities(int clientId)
{
    return ReadAllRaw()
            .Where(c => c.Id == clientId)
            .SelectMany(
                           ct => ct.ClientType
                                   .Role
                                   .PermittedActivities,
                           (s, c) => c.Uid
                       )
            .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hamlet, I really appreciate your taking the time , +1 for sure. I give a slight nod on the answer to Gert, simply because it was a bit cleaner and he was kind enough to give some further explanation. Nonetheless, it was a close call and I really do appreciate your time.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that this response was ultimately the one that I used as it was most accurate in the context. Thus, I'm switching this to the answer. Nonetheless, I am grateful for all the help from everyone.

Comment: Though I can't seem to make it look pretty, here is my final codes for anyone reading this later:                                      var permittedActivities = ReadAllRaw()
                .Where(c => c.Uid == clientUid)
                .SelectMany(
                    ct => ct.ClientType.Role.PermittedActivities,
                    (s, c) => c.Activity.Uid
                ).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

You can just 'chain' your includes together with your `navigation properties`.

```
public List<string> GetClientAndPermittedActivities(int clientId)
{
    var permittedActivities =
        ReadAllRaw()
            .Include("ClientType.Role.PermittedActivities")
            .Where(c => c.Id == clientId)
            .ToList();
}
```

That should get you all the `PermittedActivities`.

**EDIT**

If you add

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

to your class, you can use lambdas to create your statements.

```
public List<string> GetClientAndPermittedActivities(int clientId)
{
    var permittedActivities =
        ReadAllRaw().Include(x => c.ClientType.Role.PermittedActivities.SelectMany(pa => pa.Activities.Uid))
            .Where(c => c.Id == clientId)
            .ToList();
}
```

And with this you receive your requested `Activity.Uid`.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good start and taught me something that I didn't know. However, that only gets me to permitted activities - not to Activity.Uid where I need to be. If needed, I guess that I can foreach on the permitted activities and manually add to the list?

Comment: @SteveJackson I'm not 100% sure, but can you try `.Include("ClientType.Role.PermittedActivities.Activities")`? I think that should work.

Comment: Add a .Select(client => client.ClientType.Role.Select(role => role.PermittedActivity.Activity.Uid) after the Where().

Comment: Thank you user3411327, however, I tried that and I don't get Activity in my auto complete. I think it has to do with the fact that the navigation property isn't a list? Also, should I be using entity names or navigation property names for my include statement?

Comment: Should be there according to your diagramm. But you could also just select the ActivityId from the PermittedActivity. I think you need to use the NavigationProperty names.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like

```
from c in Client
where c.ClientId = clientId
from p in c.ClientType.Role.PermittedActivities
select p.Activity.Uid
```

As you see, you just start at `Client` and then follow the associations: `n - 1` is represented by a dot `.` and `1 - n` by a new `from` statement.

This is called query syntax, or comprehensive syntax. Most of the times this produces more succinct code than fluent syntax (`Client.Where(c => ...)`, although there are things you can only do with the latter.

Comment: Thank you so much Gert, that was exactly what I was after.